# I run a for loop like for(String Day : days) and I want to print data of for loop outside of for loop how to do this?

Tags: java

I run a for loop in Java like `for(String Day : days)`. I want to print data of for loop outside of for loop. How to do this?

```
 String[] day = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
  List<String> days = Arrays.asList(day);
  Collections.shuffle(days);
  
     for(String Day : days){
        //System.out.println(Day + " ");
     }

 String[] persons = {"john", "Bob", "Smith", "Tom", "Ryan"}; 
  List<String> names = Arrays.asList(persons);
  Collections.shuffle(names);
  
     for(String name : names){
        //System.out.println(name + " ");
     }
```

I want to print both like
System.out.println(name+" " + Day+" ");
but it showing error of cannot find symbol. How to fix it?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.  Completely different languages.

Comment: What does "I want to print data of for loop outside of for loop" mean? The data is already right there, outside the for loop, in the `days` list; what is it you _actually_ want to do? I.e. describe the actual result, and show what code you already tried to achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of for loop"?

Comment: i have two different for loops like this and I want to print them collectively like System.out.println(loop1+" " +loop2+ " " ); but its showing error of cannot find symbol.

Comment: What is the content? Do the arrays have the same length? What text do you expect to appear? It is still not clear what you expect. Something like `Monday 1`, `Tuesday 2`...?

Comment: i edited my question can you please check that again?

Comment: You have two lists of five entries each. You want to print the data from the same index of both lists iterating only once over the index 0..4. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @Yunnosch no i want random order everytime for all 5 entries.

Comment: Please change your [mre] to show how you are doing that (including the random part) for one list, then for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to print both like System.out.println(name+" " + Day+" "); but
> it showing error of cannot find symbol. how to fix it?

The scope of the variables, `Day` and `name` is limited to the loops where they have been declared and therefore trying to access them outside their loops will cause compilation failure.

You can fix it by accessing the elements based on indices.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] day = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
        List<String> days = Arrays.asList(day);
        Collections.shuffle(days);

        String[] persons = { "john", "Bob", "Smith", "Tom", "Ryan" };
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(persons);
        Collections.shuffle(names);

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.min(days.size(), names.size()); i++) {
            System.out.println(names.get(i) + "\t" + days.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
john    Friday
Ryan    Thursday
Tom Tuesday
Bob Wednesday
Smith   Monday
```

Comment: thats what i needed. thanks alot

Comment: @SukhwinderpalSingh - You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Comment: along with this i want to add random numbers as well for which I have code            
      int min = 3;
      int max = 10;
      Random rand = new Random();
      
      int a = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
      int b = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
      int c = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
      int d = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
      int e = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;

Comment: @SukhwinderpalSingh - You can use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) to generate a random number is a range. I suggest you post a new question regarding this requirement so that someone can answer that. The general guideline on Stackoverflow is that a question should be focused to one problem.

Comment: I post question can you please help me in that. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67131150/15663999?sem=2 here is the link