# i have code of random number and random names

Tags: java

i am making code of each time when prompt system will generate random order of names and day.  in the last there is for loop which is generating random order of names and day. in this for loop I want to add random number  as well for which I written the code as well. can someone help me in printing random number along with this.

```
 String[] engineers = {"john", "Bob", "Smith", "Tom", "Ryan"}; 
  List<String> names = Arrays.asList(engineers);
  Collections.shuffle(names);
     
  // for generating randon number 
  int min = 3;
  int max = 10;
  Random rand = new Random();
  
  int a = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
  int b = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
  int c = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
  int d = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
  int e = rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
  
  //System.out.println(a);
  //System.out.println(b);
  //System.out.println(c);
  //System.out.println(d);
  //System.out.println(e);
  
  // for shuffle day generation
  String[] day = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
  List<String> days = Arrays.asList(day);
  Collections.shuffle(days);  
  
     for(int i = 0; i < Integer.min(days.size(), names.size()); i++){
        System.out.println("Engineer : " + names.get(i) + " "+ ";"+ " " + "Shift Day : " + days.get(i) + "Shift hours : " + );
     }
```

Comment: Can you please describe the expected behaviour?

Comment: i want system will print in one line                                                                                 
1 - name , random number between 3 to 10 , day                                                                   2 - name , random number between 3 to 10, day as so for all 5 entries randomly

Comment: Still not sure if I got you right. But if I understood that correct:
```System.out.println("Engineer : " + names.get(i) + " "+ ";"+ (rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min) +" " + "Shift Day : " + days.get(i) + "Shift hours : " + );```

Comment: thats i already did above. i want the random number to be printed in for loop

Comment: You want the random numbers a to e printed in a for loop?

Comment: If you wanna create this numbers upfront put them into an array to access them via the index in the for loop. Otherwise create them on demand with the for loop ```rand.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min```

Comment: @TobiSH thanksalot man you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

From your comment, I understood that you want the same random index to be used for `names` and `days`.

For this, instead of generating random numbers for indices, you can store integers from 0 to the size of one of the list and randomize this list. Then, use the values from this randomized list as the index to retrieve values from the two lists. This will also ensure that no line is a duplicate of any other line.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] day = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
        List<String> days = Arrays.asList(day);

        String[] persons = { "john", "Bob", "Smith", "Tom", "Ryan" };
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(persons);

        // Store indices into a List and randomize it
        List<Integer> randIndices = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < day.length; i++) {
            randIndices.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(randIndices);

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.min(days.size(), names.size()); i++) {
            int index = randIndices.get(i);
            System.out.println("Day " + index + ": " + days.get(index) + ", Engineer: " + names.get(index));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output of a sample run:**

```
Day 2: Wednesday, Engineer: Smith
Day 4: Friday, Engineer: Ryan
Day 0: Monday, Engineer: john
Day 1: Tuesday, Engineer: Bob
Day 3: Thursday, Engineer: Tom
```

### Original answer

I suggest you use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(int origin, int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) to generate a pseudorandom `int` index value between the specified origin (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).

Also, since you are using random indices, [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) is unnecessary in this case.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] day = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
        List<String> days = Arrays.asList(day);
        // Collections.shuffle(days); // Unnecessary

        String[] persons = { "john", "Bob", "Smith", "Tom", "Ryan" };
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList(persons);
        // Collections.shuffle(names); // Unnecessary

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.min(days.size(), names.size()); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%n", names.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, i + 1)),
                    days.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, i + 1)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output of a sample run:**

```
john           Monday         
Bob            Tuesday        
john           Tuesday        
Bob            Wednesday      
Tom            Thursday
```

Comment: i want same as you answer earlier with that I want random numbers